# Show that if $a^h ≡ 1\mod p$ then $ a^{ph} ≡ 1 \ \mod p^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I don't know how to proceed.
I know that regardless of what h is, it divides the order of a modulo $p$.
I also know that the order of a divides $\phi(p) \ \text{mod} \ p$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.
Hence, by the transitive property, $h$ divides $\phi(p)\ \text{mod} \ p$.
But I don't know where to go from here...or if I'm even going in the right direction.

h is not necessarily the order of $a$, right? (Because we don't know if it's the least $h$ such that $a^h$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$).

Help please.

Comment: No, $h$ doesn't necessarily divide the order of $a$ mod $p$. It's the other way around. In any case, the $h$ is totally irrelevant to the problem. Indeed $x\equiv y~(p)\implies x^p\equiv y^p~(p^2)$.

Comment: Thank you blue. You're right, it is the other way around.
Also, the last part of your comment makes my problem rather trivial, no? Haha, well it is the first part of my problem, the second of which I left out from the thread because I wanted to try for myself. But thanks for your help!

Comment: The last part of my comment indeed makes the problem trivial, because it is a generalization of the fact you're trying to prove. Anything is trivial if you were hypothetically able to justify it with something stronger.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
a^h = 1+kp
$$
so
$$
a^{ph} = (1+kp)^p = 1 + kp^2 + \sum_{j=2}^p {p\choose j}k^jp^j
$$
and $p^2$ divides every term other than the first one.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Vaidyanathan.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We have $a^h=1+kp$ for some $k$. Take the $p$-th power, using the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I got it now.

Comment: You are welcome. There is little number-theoretic machinery involved.